# How to implement a layout like the new layout of google images?

Tags: layout

When the width of the brower is changed,  the image's width or height is also changed dynamically, anyone knows how to do it?
And I found the image's max height of each rows is not the same.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure Google's image application is a little more complicated than can be written in a single post, but you could mimic some of the effect with some clever use of jQuery. Here's a quick tutorial on a resizeable image grid using a slider -

[Image resize tutorial](http://webdesignledger.com/tutorials/create-a-resizable-image-grid-with-jquery)

You would need to change the trigger from a slider to the resize event, but this has the basics you need.